# Reference counting without Garbage Collection

Tags: garbage-collection, reference-counting

I am taking a course on programming language design, and one of the topics is Garbage Collection. I understood from the material that RC *can* be used for GC, but that it also has other uses, and that some languages implement RC but not GC.
What exactly is the use of RC if not for GC?

(***RC*** - reference counting. ***GC*** - garbage collection)

Comment: It should be noted that the term "garbage collection" doesn't have a real tightly specified meaning.  What's GC to one person may not be considered GC to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference counting may be used, eg, to close unreferenced file handles, or to somehow "archive" currently unreferenced data (that can potentially be rereferenced through some indirect path in the future).

Answer (score 2):

I can provide a specific example of reference counting used independently of garbage collection. Objective-C uses reference counting to manage the lifetime of its objects, without the presence of a garbage collector in most cases.

This is done through balanced calls to `-retain` and `-release` when dealing with objects. Basically, an object is created with a retain count of 1, and every object that needs to hold on to a reference to an object should increase its retain count by 1 when being passed it initially, then decrement the retain count by 1 when done with it. The final `-release` call that causes the object's retain count to drop to 0 (no one should have a need for it anymore) triggers the internal mechanisms of the object type to deallocate itself.

No garbage collector process is required for this to take place. In fact, there wasn't a garbage collector for this on Apple's platforms (who are by far the largest users of Objective-C) until fairly recently, and that's not even used for its iOS mobile devices (and is now deprecated on the Mac desktop).

The reference counting in Objective-C is by default manual in nature, requiring developers to follow certain conventions to make sure that you safely balance retain and release calls to avoid leaks or premature deallocations. A newer system was just implemented within the LLVM compiler that automates this, and adds the appropriate calls at compile-time. This automatic reference counting removes much of the effort of managing memory while removing the need for a garbage collector process to sweep object graphs.

One specific condition that a garbage collector can handle that reference counting cannot is the detection and removal of retain cycles. Objects that hold strong references to that point back upon themselves in a cycle will never be deallocated under standard reference counting, even if all objects referencing those in the cycle release the references to those within it. A garbage collector will see that this cycle is not rooted in the larger object graph and will be able to remove the entire cycle when it performs a sweep.

Comment: Isn't this garbage collection? Automatic removal/disposal of objects *is* GC!

Comment: @baruch - No, reference counting still requires the developer to state when an object is being retained and released. No collector process is required to sweep through memory and determine which objects are no longer being referenced, an object is deallocated at the instant that a developer passes the last release to it (which isn't always sent at the right time). As I state, Objective-C, while reference counted, has both garbage collected and non garbage collected implementations (with the former being much more popular).

Comment: That is a type of garbage collection.  Not fully automatic, but still GC.  GC does not necessarily involve a "sweep" to find unreferenced items.  In fact, the Java-style GC is a relatively recent invention.